# Proper way to bind SQL NULL to ASP.NET Control?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, null, bind

I have an ASP.NET control that I have bound to a SQL result:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EmployeeSearchResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# (EmployeeSearchStatus(Eval("SeparationDate"),Eval("PositionTitle"),Eval("EffectiveDate"))) %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                                                
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My EmployeeSearchStatus function is very basic, testing the values passed in for NULL, and creating a string to display:

```
Public Function EmployeeSearchStatus(ByVal SeparationDate As Object, ByVal PositionTitle As Object, ByVal EffectiveDate As Object) As String
  Dim ReturnString As String = ""
    If IsDBNull(SeparationDate) Then
      ReturnString = "Currently Employed as "
    Else
      ReturnString = "Last Employed as "
    End If
    ReturnString += PositionTitle
    If IsDBNull(SeparationDate) Then
        ReturnString += " (effective " + EffectiveDate + ")."
    Else
        ReturnString += " (separated on " + SeparationDate + ")."
    End If
    Return ReturnString
End Function
```

Is this the proper way to handle NULL values coming back from SQL to an ASP.NET control?  Is there a better technique?

Thanks,

Russell

Comment: you arent really using classic asp here, are you? This looks like .net. If so, you might be better off tagging the question with asp.net and not asp-classic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, although you could possibly simplify it a bit if you wanted:

```
Public Function EmployeeSearchStatus(ByVal SeparationDate As Object, ByVal PositionTitle As Object, ByVal EffectiveDate As Object) As String
    If IsDBNull(SeparationDate) Then
        Return "Currently Employed as " + PositionTitle + " (effective " + EffectiveDate + ")."
    Else
        Return "Last Employed as " + PositionTitle + " (separated on " + SeparationDate + ")."
    End If
End Function
```

The code does assume, however, that `PositionTitle` and `EffectiveDate` will never be `null`. If this is not enforced in the database, you could add some checks to the code to deal with these situations.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I know it works and recognize the simplification (thank you).  Is this the most elegant way to handle nulls?  :-)

Comment: I don't know if it is the **most** elegant, but it seems appropriate, readable and maintainable to me. The only change I could think of to make would be to change `IsDBNull` (which is VB specific) to `column Is System.DbNull.Value`, which I believe should work across all .NET. This would only be relevant if you were later planning to refactor your code to another language.

Comment: Thanks Paul, C# may be in our future so I appreciate the forward thinking.  :-)   Russell